# Summing columns from different dataframe according to some column names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have a main dataframe

```
main_df

  Cri1  Cri2   Cr3  total
0   A1    A2    A3  4
1   B1    B2    B3  5
2   C1    C2    C3  6
```

I also have 3 dataframes

```
df_1

      Cri1   Cri2  Cri3 value
    0   A1    A2    A3  1
    1   B1    B2    B3  2

df_2
      Cri1  Cri2  Cri3  value
    0   A1    A2    A3  9
    1   C1    C2    C3  10

df_3
      Cri1  Cri2  Cri3  value
    0   B1    B2    B3  15
    1   C1    C2    C3  17
```

What I want is to add value from each frame `df` to total in the `main_df` according to Cri
i.e. main_df will become

main_df

```
      Cri1  Cri2  Cri3  total
    0   A1    A2    A3  14
    1   B1    B2    B3  22
    2   C1    C2    C3  33
```

Of course I can do it using for loop, but at the end I want to apply the method to a large amount of data, say 50000 rows in each dataframe.

Is there other ways to solve it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

First you should align your numeric column names. In this case:

```
df_main = df_main.rename(columns={'total': 'value'})
```

Then you have a couple of options.

#### concat + groupby

You can concatenate and then perform a `groupby` with `sum`:

```
res = pd.concat([df_main, df_1, df_2, df_3])\
        .groupby(['Cri1', 'Cri2', 'Cri3']).sum()\
        .reset_index()

print(res)

  Cri1 Cri2 Cri3  value
0   A1   A2   A3     14
1   B1   B2   B3     22
2   C1   C2   C3     33
```

#### set_index + reduce / add

Alternatively, you can create a list of dataframes indexed by your criteria columns. Then use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) with [`pd.DataFrame.add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html) to sum these dataframes.

```
from functools import reduce

dfs = [df.set_index(['Cri1', 'Cri2', 'Cri3']) for df in [df_main, df_1, df_2, df_3]]

res = reduce(lambda x, y: x.add(y, fill_value=0), dfs).reset_index()

print(res)

  Cri1 Cri2 Cri3  value
0   A1   A2   A3   14.0
1   B1   B2   B3   22.0
2   C1   C2   C3   33.0
```